# How to import js file(s) inside vue component (laravel)

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuejs2, laravel-6.2, laravel-vue

I have a **form.js** stored in my **resource/js/**

```
class Form{
    constructor(){
        //more coding here
    }

    //more coding here
}
```

My question is how can I import the file above inside my .vue file? I tried these below:

```
<template>
    //some html here
</template>

<script src="../form.js"></script>
<script>

    export default{
        data(){
            return {
                form: new Form({
                    title: '',
                    body: ''
                })
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

But still getting these error:

> [Vue warn]: Error in data(): "ReferenceError: Form is not defined"

---

**PROBLEM SOLVED**:

```
export default class Form{
   //more coding here
}
```

`import Form from '../form.js';`

Comment: @Antonio already there from that link but does not work. I tried these `import Form from '../form.js';` from that link but returns me an error **[Vue warn]: Error in data(): "TypeError: _form_js__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0___default.a is not a constructor"**

Comment: Did you add `export default` in form.js? `export default class Form { ... }`

Comment: @Antonio already added Sir. Heres new error in my console **[Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: _vm.form.errors.has is not a function"**

Comment: @Antonio the `Form class` actually working when inline to my vue file. But this time I want to separate it for multiple usage.

Comment: Could you provide codepen?

Comment: @Antonio okey wait sir

Comment: @Antonio https://codepen.io/escbooster12/project/editor/AVpbNz two files there Sir. I'm not really mastered using codepen. but there is two files there.

Comment: @Antonio already solved, thank you sir! already solved. I forgot I put it in the error class instead of form class. I'm so noob sorry.

Comment: Ah, are there another class `Errors`?

Comment: @Antonio yes Sir. I forgot I put the export to my Errors class instead of Form class. Glad it works now. thanks again.